# How do I prove that the product of two integers is less than twice the integer formed when they are concatenated?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How do I prove that the product of two integers is always less than the integer formed when they are concatenated and multiplied by two given that the initial integers have same number of digits?

How to prove that A*B is always less than 2 * (--AB--) where  (--AB--) integer formed after concatenating A and B?

Comment: What do you mean "concatenated" Do you mean the base 10 strings are concatenated?

Comment: HINT: 9974=99*100+74.  Why is this more than 99*74?

Comment: It's not remotely clear why you need the multiple of $2$.

Comment: Obfuscation is a good reason.

Comment: Write (--AB--) as $100A+B$

Comment: thanks all the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A and B be $n$ digit numbers. Clearly, $A<10^n$ and $B<10^n$. Note that: $$(A\times10^n+B)-AB=A(10^n-B)+B>0$$ as $10^n>B$. Therefore, $(A\times10^n+B)-AB>0\implies (A\times10^n+B)>AB$, which was required, as $(A\times10^n+B)$ is the number you get by concatenating $A$ and $B$.